# Min and max value per group keeping order

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a small problem in Redshift with with grouping; I have a table like following:

INPUT

```
VALUE       CREATED       UPDATED
------------------------------------
1        '2020-09-10'   '2020-09-11'
1        '2020-09-11'   '2020-09-13'
2        '2020-09-15'   '2020-09-16'
1        '2020-09-17'   '2020-09-18'
```

I want to obtain this output:

```
VALUE       CREATED       UPDATED
------------------------------------
1        '2020-09-10'   '2020-09-13'
2        '2020-09-15'   '2020-09-16'
1        '2020-09-17'   '2020-09-18'
```

If I do a simple Min and Max date grouping by the value, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a gap-and-islands problem.  If there are no time gaps in the data, then a difference of row numbers is a simple solution:

```
select value, min(created), max(updated)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by created) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by created) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by value, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by min(created);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference between the row numbers identifies adjacent rows with the same `value`.

Comment: Hi, Gordon, thanks for the quick answer, it works perfectly, but what do you mean per gap in the data ?

Comment: @nasshy . . . Basically, this ignores the `updated` column, assuming that it always matches the next `created`.

Comment: yes i have this problem but on top of this table i was thinking to replace the created  column by the updated column of previous row with a LAG() function.